# How can I install apps with uiautomator?

Tags: android-uiautomator

My app to test depends on Facebook. On such devices which does not have Facebook installed, I needs to install Facebook first.

The first way I have tried is to install it from an APK file. However, I cannot find any APIs to achieve this from uiautomator developer docs. I guess this is determined by the design of uiautomator.

The second way I have tried is to install it from Google Play store. However, on the devices which has no Google account signed in, I need to sign in Google account first. I tried to sign in using uiautomator but unfortunately the sign-in page is NAF (not accessibility friendly).

Does anyone know if there is any other ways? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) is a pure python tool that automates or simplifies test script creation. The scripts use UiAutomator as a backend.

[Culebra GUI](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Culebra-GUI) can generate tests that include the installation of an APK as a precondition.

```
culebra --install-apk=file.apk --unit-test-class --gui
```

### EDIT

`culebra` only generates python, so if you want to generate **Java** or **Kotlin**  you may need [CulebraTester](http://culebra.dtmilano.com/).

However, due to the limited connectivity and capabilities when you run those tests in Firebase Test Lab it might be challenging to find a way of installing dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This tool looks great.
But I want the java implementation using UiAutomator APIs because I needs to deploy the test to run on Firebase test lab which accepts UiAutomator 2.0 tests only.